# Magento: Display number of times a product has been sold in the Product Grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am looking to add a column to the product grid (in the admin area to be clear) to display how many times this product has been sold. Here is what I have so far after piecing together from several other posts:

In app/code/local/Namespace/Qtysold/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Qtysold_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
/* Overwritten to be able to add custom columns to the product grid. Normally
 * one would overwrite the function _prepareCollection, but it won't work because
 * you have to call parent::_prepareCollection() first to get the collection.
 *
 * But since parent::_prepareCollection() also finishes the collection, the
 * joins and attributes to select added in the overwritten _prepareCollection()
 * are 'forgotten'.
 *
 * By overwriting setCollection (which is called in parent::_prepareCollection()),
 * we are able to add the join and/or attribute select in a proper way.
 *
 */
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */

    $store = $this->_getStore();

    if ($store->getId() && !isset($this->_joinAttributes['qty_sold'])) {
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'qty_sold',
            'reports/product_collection',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            $store->getId()
        );
    }
    else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('qty_sold');
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump((string) $collection->getSelect());
    echo "</pre>";

    parent::setCollection($collection);
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $this->addColumnAfter('qty_sold',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty Sold'),
            'type'  => 'number',
            'index' => 'qty_sold',
        ),
        'price'
     );

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}
```

A couple of things here. 1) $store->getId() returns 0 so it never goes into that first block in setCollection, is that correct behavior since it is the Admin area? 2) If I force the joinAttribute to run, it causes an exception (Invalid entity...) which is sort of expected since reports doesn't appear to really be an entity, but I'm not really clear on this whole entity business. 3) In other examples (like this one: http://www.creativemediagroup.net/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/30-show-quantity-sold-on-product-page-magento) they use something like this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
->getFirstItem();
```

And I am not sure if there is any way to "join" with this reports/product_collection or if there is any way to recreate its "addOrderedQty" data?

This is on Magento 1.7. I can provide further details as needed. I am a beginner with Magento development so any help at all (including resources to learn) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Admin Area does have the store ID = 0, so yes this will always be returned.

this will also mean your conditional always fails and never does any joining, it will just try and add the qty_sold to the collection, which of course will not work as it's not part of that entities data.

The issue is the joinAttribute method will only work on "Entites" (it depends on the classes used by the models you are trying to join), and as the reports/product collection isn't one of these you will have to join another way using methods like this:

```
join() or joinLeft()
```

with this kind of thing:

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
    'customer_entity',
    'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id',
     array('customer_name' => 'email')
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Was also dealing with this issue and solved it as follows:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    // [...]
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    // Add subquery join to sales_flat_order_item to get a SUM of how many times this product has been ordered
    $totalOrderedQuery = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
        ->select()
        ->from('sales_flat_order_item', array('product_id', 'qty_ordered' => 'SUM(`qty_ordered`)'))
        ->group('product_id');

    $collection->joinField('qty_ordered', $totalOrderedQuery, 'qty_ordered', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left');
    // [...]
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Note the usage of `$collection->joinField()`, tried using the mentioned `$collection->getSelect()->join()`, but it gives all sorts of issues with sort orders and filtering due to the internal Magento data collection not recognizing the column as part of the data set.

Then in `_prepareColumns` you can simply add the column:

```
$this->addColumn('qty_ordered', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('xyz')->__('Total quantity ordered'),
    'sortable' => true,
    'width' => '10%',
    'index' => 'qty_ordered',
));
```

You might want to add a renderer which checks and converts a `NULL` value to `'0'`, otherwise you will end up with empty columns if the product hasn't been ordered yet (you could also fix this in the SELECT query by using [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for `qty_ordered`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed (though it is hardly perfect) thanks to that tip from Andrew. Here is my updated code for setCollection:

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */

    $store = $this->_getStore();

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('oi' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
        'e.entity_id = oi.product_id',
        array("qty_sold" => 'SUM(oi.qty_ordered)')
    )->group('e.entity_id');

    parent::setCollection($collection);
}
```

I was curious if any Magento developers see a serious flaw in this approach (I'm aware of some of the business logic such as not counting products that were canceled, etc) or recommendations for a better approach. Either way this is "good enough" for now and meets my needs, so I'll post in case others need it.